# Lightweight syntax for filtering a polars DataFrame on a multi-column key?

Tags: python-polars

I'm wondering if there's a lightweight syntax for filtering a polars DataFrame against a multi-column key, other than inner/anti joins. (There's nothing wrong with the joins, but it would be nice if there's something more compact).

Using the following frame as an example:

```py
import polars as pl
df = pl.DataFrame( 
    data = [
        ["x",123, 4.5, "misc"],
        ["y",456,10.0,"other"],
        ["z",789,99.5,"value"],
    ],
    columns = ["a","b","c","d"],
)
```

A PostgreSQL statement could use a VALUES expression, like so...

```sql
(("a","b") IN (VALUES ('x',123),('y',456)))
```

...and a pandas equivalent might set a multi-column index.

```py
pf.set_index( ["a","b"], inplace=True )
pf[ pf.index.isin([('x',123),('y',456)]) ]
```

The polars syntax would look like this:

```py
df.join( 
    pl.DataFrame(
        data = [('x',123),('y',456)],
        columns = {col:tp for col,tp in df.schema.items() if col in ("a","b")},
        orient = 'row',
    ),
    on = ["a","b"],
    how = "inner", # or 'anti' for "not in"
)
```

Is a multi-column `is_in` construct, or equivalent expression, currently available with polars? Something like the following would be great if it exists (or could be added):

```py
df.filter( pl.cols("a","b").is_in([('x',123),('y',456)]) )
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: One thought: creating a struct from "a","b" and then using `is_in` might work.  https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/3463 (feature request).  (Also, it might be helpful if there was an easy syntax for creating the list of struct)

Comment: @cbilot Thanks; I had a go with structs, but was blocked by the same errors and subsequently found your feature request... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the next polars release `>0.13.44` this will work on the `struct` datatype.

We convert the 2 (or more) columns we want to check to a struct with `pl.struct` and call the `is_in` expression. (A conversion to `struct` is a free operation)

```py
df = pl.DataFrame(
    data=[
        ["x", 123, 4.5, "misc"],
        ["y", 456, 10.0, "other"],
        ["z", 789, 99.5, "value"],
    ],
    columns=["a", "b", "c", "d"],
)

df.filter(
    pl.struct(["a", "b"]).is_in([{"a": "x", "b": 123}, {"a": "y", "b": 456}])
)
```

```
shape: (2, 4)
┌─────┬─────┬──────┬───────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ c    ┆ d     │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---  ┆ ---   │
│ str ┆ i64 ┆ f64  ┆ str   │
╞═════╪═════╪══════╪═══════╡
│ x   ┆ 123 ┆ 4.5  ┆ misc  │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ y   ┆ 456 ┆ 10.0 ┆ other │
└─────┴─────┴──────┴───────┘
```

## Filtering by data in another DataFrame.

The idiomatic way to filter data by presence in another `DataFrame` are **semi** and **anti** joins. **Inner** joins also filter by presence, but they include the columns of the right hand DataFrame, where a **semi** join does not and only filters the left hand side.

- semi: keep rows/keys that are in both DataFrames
- anti: remove rows/keys that are in both DataFrames

The reason why these joins are preferred over `is_in` is that they are much faster and currently allow for more optimization.

Comment: Great, thanks; I'd identified `anti`, but `semi` was the missing piece of the puzzle for the best performance - I have a thin shim in front of the syntax, so I should be able to convert any multi-column constraints into the matching joins under the hood (maybe something for a future optimizer update? :).

Comment: (The updated struct-matching support is much-appreciated too)